# Facing error when using buttons from discord components in cogs Discord.py

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
bot = discord.ext.commands.Bot(command_prefix = ";");
import random
from asyncio import TimeoutError
import subprocess
import sys
from discord_components import *

class GameCommands(commands.Cog):
  
  def __init__(self, bot):
    self.bot=bot

  @commands.Cog.listener()
  async def on_ready(self):
    DiscordComponents(bot)
    print('ready')
  @commands.command() 
  async def rps(self,ctx):
    choices=['rock','paper','scissors']
    bot_choise=random.choice(choices)
    player_choise=""
    yet= discord.Embed(title=f"{ctx.author.display_name}'s Rock Paper Scissors Game", description="Click On A Button", color=discord.Color.from_rgb(0, 208, 255))
    won= discord.Embed(title=f"You Won! Le Hurray!", description=f"You chose {player_choise} and the Bot chose {bot_choise}", color=discord.Color.from_rgb(255, 213, 0))
    lost= discord.Embed(title=f"You Lost! Sadge :(", description=f"You chose {player_choise} and the Bot chose {bot_choise}", color=discord.Color.from_rgb(102, 61, 69))
    tie= discord.Embed(title=f"Hmm, A tie!", description=f"You and the bot both chose {bot_choise}", color=discord.Color.from_rgb(137, 49, 181))
    out= discord.Embed(title=f"Timeout ", description=f"You didn't choose any option in time, Bruh!", color=discord.Color.from_rgb(43, 194, 146))

    m = await ctx.send(embed=yet,components=[[Button(style=1 ,label="Rock"),Button(style=3 ,label="Paper"),Button(style=4 ,label="Scissors")]])

    def check(res):
      return ctx.author==res.user and res.channel==ctx.channel
    try:
      res= await self.bot.wait_for("button_click", check=check, timeout=15)
      player_choise= res.component.label

      if player_choise==bot_choise:
        await m.edit(embed=tie, components=[])

      if player_choise=="Paper" and bot_choise=="Rock":
        await m.edit(embed=won, components=[])

      if player_choise=="Scissors" and bot_choise=="Paper":
        await m.edit(embed=won, components=[])

      if player_choise=="Rock" and bot_choise=="Scissors":
        await m.edit(embed=won, components=[])

      if player_choise=="Rock" and bot_choise=="Paper":
        await m.edit(embed=lost, components=[])

      if player_choise=="Paper" and bot_choise=="Scissor":
        await m.edit(embed=lost, components=[])

      if player_choise=="Scissor" and bot_choise=="Rock":
        await m.edit(embed=lost, components=[])

    except TimeoutError:
      await m.edit(embed=out, components=[])
def setup(bot):
  bot.add_cog(GameCommands(bot))
```

I have discord-components installed, whenever i run the command i get this error:

```
Ignoring exception in command rps:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/runner/TheDuck/commands/games.py", line 37, in rps
    m = await ctx.send(embed=yet,components=[[Button(style=1 ,label="Rock"),Button(style=3 ,label="Paper"),Button(style=4 ,label="Scissors")]])
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord_components/client.py", line 46, in send_component_msg_prop
    return await self.send_component_msg(ctxorchannel.channel, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord_components/client.py", line 177, in send_component_msg
    data = await self.bot.http.request(
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/http.py", line 192, in request
    async with self.__session.request(method, url, **kwargs) as r:
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'request'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 939, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 863, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'request'
```

I don't know what is causing this error. I tried finding about it online but couldn't.
I would Like to know what possible mistake i might be making or is it a bug.
I saw almost the same code being run on the main file without any problems. Is it a problem with cogs or my code is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

While I am unsure if that is a bug or not, I think it would be better to use Discord.py 2.0 (Currently in Alpha) for buttons instead of third party libs. Keep in mind it might be unstable so is your choice.